# Why do I keep getting this "Reading SConscript files" error?

Tags: python, plugins, command-line

I'm trying to install this tool on my windows computer going on 2 weeks now. After cloning the repository from GitHub, the instructions clearly says to go to my top-level source directory and type `scons` in order to build Alta on my machine. However, every time I use scans in my command line, I get the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jjohnson497-gtri/Documents/Greg/alta/SConstruct", line 38

    print '<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:'

          ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:')?
```

The first part of SConstruct code:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2014, 2015 CNRS
# Copyright (C) 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 Inria
# Copyright (C) 2015 Universite de Montreal
#
# This file is part of ALTA.
#
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0.  If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

import os
import sys
import SCons.SConf as C

# Arrange so that the 'obtain' module can always be imported.
top_srcdir = Dir('.').srcnode().abspath
sys.path += [ top_srcdir + '/external' ]

## Add ALTA custom cmd configurations
##
AddOption('--cfg', help='Specify a configuration file')


## Import configuration from a config file
##
configFile = GetOption('cfg')
if configFile == None:

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-windows-cl.py"
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-macos-clang.py"
    elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
        configFile = "./configs/scons/config-linux-gcc.py"
    else:
        print '<<ERROR>> You need to specify a configuration file using:'
        print '<<ERROR>>    scons --cfg=[filename]'
        print '<<ERROR>> Please find example of configuration files in ${ALTA}/configs/scons/'
        Exit(1)
#end
```

Why is it giving me an error to fix the script that I have imported? I shouldn't have to change anything if it is proven to work. I even tried specifying using flags like such  `scons --cfg=./configs/scons/config-linux-gcc.py`. This is the page I am referring to: http://alta.gforge.inria.fr/install.html

Comment: "Why is it giving me an error to fix the script that I have imported?" Because the script does not work under Python 3.x. This is not a programming question, it is a tech support question, which you should take to the developers. I wouldn't be optimistic, though - it appears that no work has been done on the project in at least two years.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel   ok, thank you. If you don't mind me asking, how do you know that the script doesn't work under python 3.x?

Comment: Because under 3.x, `print` is now a function rather than a statement, which is why the error that you report occurs.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hey I'm back. Quick question, is there a way to determine which version of python the Sconstruct is compatible with? I would think its compatible with 2.7.18, but I still get the same errors.